# Separate config files for different Desktop Environment

Tags: linux, linux-mint, xfce, i3

How can i have separate .bashrc or config files for different desktop environment. Like i have i3gaps and XFCE installed but i want to have different configuration for those desktop environment

Comment: You can create several users.

Comment: That was a great idea...